# Elastic search /solr architecture

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I am looking for a solution for elastic search for following use case.

I have a portal which there are several modules, such as News, Announcements, etc.

I want to store them in Elastic search and search for it. However, not sure how i should architecture it so that, I can search a given term in every module within Portal.

However, as far as I understand elastic search there are indexes per Entity.

What would be a good design both for entire site search and per entity content search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With elasticsearch you can search across types and across indices. I would start off with just using one index and use multiple types for each bucket of information/entity. Each type gets its own schema, but you can share all the custom index analyzers and index API functionality across the types. If you need to break it up into separate indexes eventually, it won't be a problem.

Indexes and types are just logical containers in ElasticSearch. They give you complete freedom to match your data needs. Site search or entity only search can structure using single index with multiple types or multiple indexes.

The key is to just get started without getting stuck in the architecture, the architecture required will reveal itself pretty quickly during development.